# Problem changing the /home directory to another location

Tags: debian, home

I decided to move my `/home` directory to a separate parition. But, since I am using more than one linux distro, I want to separate the `/home` directories as follows:

```
/dev/sdax/ubuntu
/dev/sdax/debian
/dev/sdax/suse
```

After copying all the neccessary files to this folder, I changed the `/etc/fstab` to mount the new `/home` location as the default home drive

```
/dev/sdax    /homedrive ext4 nodev,nosuid 0 2
/homedrive/debian /home bind default,bind 0 0
```

Now, as far as I can see while starting up debian, it is mounting the folder properly, but while I try to login it gives an error:

> Could not update ICEauthority file /home/user-name/.ICEauthority

And after closing that message I get:

> There is problem with the configuration server (/usr/libexec/gconf-sanity-check-2 ...

What's going wrong?

Comment: Are the permissions of the home directory set properly? ls -l /home/user-name

Comment: Yes, I think. The permission is 644

Comment: How about the files in the directory, specifically .ICEauthority? And is the owner/group set properly too?

Comment: I am not sure about that? How to check it and change, since I am not able to log in.

Comment: What are the permissions of the `.ICEauthority` file? Could you also post the output of `ls -la /home/`?

Comment: @stars 644 is wrong, home directories need execute permissions set so the directory is browsable so try 755.

Comment: are the directories chowned correctly? it's possible the users in different distro's don't all have the same userID so when booting into different distro's it thinks the directories are owned by different users.

Comment: @Ardesco I also thought so at first, but note that the asker keeps the home directory from each distro in a separate folder.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz but you don't know how the files have been moved from the original /home to /homedrive/debian, if for instance they have been `cp -r`ed as root all the files would be owned by root...

Comment: @Source Lab, I couldn't understand what you said. Could you say in a simpler language.

Comment: Starx: Please explain, exactly **how did you create or copy the home directories** (`/homedrive/debian`, `/homedrive/ubuntu`, `/homedrive/suse`).

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz, using `find . -depth -print0 | cpio --null --sparse -pvd /newlocation/`

Comment: When copying directories under Linux, use **`cp -a`** unless you know you want different options. By default, `cp` does not preserve permissions completely and does not preserve ownership or file modification times; `-a` tells `cp` to preserve everything. Not preserving ownership is what caused your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/separatehome). Wrote the following command and it worked.

```
chown -R username:username /home/username
chmod 644 /home/username/.dmrc
chmod 644 /home/username/.ICEauthority
```

Answer (score 2):

You can login to a terminal as root (on Debian you should have set a root password when you installed) by pressing [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[F1] once your system have booted. You can then check that the permissions is correct with this commenad

```
ls -ld /home/user/
```

and

```
ls -l /home/user/.ICEauthority
```

change ownership with

```
chown user: /home/user
```

and permissions with

```
chmod mode /home/user/file
```

Permissions on your home folder should be 755 or 750 and on the .ICEauthority file is should be 600.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have copied the home directories without properly preserving the ownerships of files/folders. From `info cpio`:

```
`--no-preserve-owner'
     Do not change the ownership of the files; leave them owned by the
     user extracting them.  This is the default for non-root users, so
     that users on System V don't inadvertantly give away files.  This
     option can be used in copy-in mode and copy-pass mode
```

So you should repeat the operation *as root* - either the same way you did, or using the simpler `cp -a` command.

*edit: I see you've just solved it. So it confirmed the issue was with ownerships.*

Comment: Should I include `--no-preserve-owner` in the command I wrote to copy the files?

Comment: @Starx No no no - this should NOT be used in your case. But it is the **default** option for non-root users - that is why I posted it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
/dev/sdax/ubuntu
/dev/sdax/debian
/dev/sdax/suse
```

I sincerely hope you're not creating data directories on the dev filesystem!

```
/dev/sdax    /homedrive ext4 nodev,nosuid 0 2
/homedrive/debian /home bind default,bind 0 0
```

OK so it looks like you're not - but its still a strange way to set up the filesystem. I assume you've got 3 different directories set up on the same filesystem...

A better way to solve this would be to use different symlinks in each distro to the location of /home

```
mount /dev/sdax /homedrives
cp -R -p /home /homedrives/${currentdistro}
rm -r -f /home
ln -s /homedrives/${currentdistro} /home
```

Comment: mount bind or sym-links accomplish exactly the same in this case.. I can't see how one should be better than the other!